# PHP ftp_nlist() returning false even in passive mode

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to connect to ftp_nlist() a server with the following code :

```
$ftpStream = ftp_connect($host,$port);

if($ftpStream!=false)
{
    echo 'ftp_connect() worked </br>';
    echo 'Hostname = ' . $host . '</br>';
    $login=ftp_login($ftpStream,$username,$password);
    if($login!=false)
    {
        echo 'Logged in </br>';
        $pasvMode = ftp_pasv($ftpStream, true);
        if($pasvMode!=false)
        {
            echo 'Passive mode </br>';
            $nlist=ftp_list($ftpStream,'.');
            var_dump($nlist);
        }

        else
            echo 'ftp_pasv() failed </br>';
    }
    else
         echo 'Failed to log in </br>';
}
else
    echo 'ftp_connect() failed </br>';
```

I'm successfully connected and logged in, passive mode is also activated, but ftp_nlist() is still returning false. Do you know if it is possible for a FTP server to forbid some commands (like ftp_nlist(), ftp_rawlist()...) because I can get everything from FileZilla, and nothing from PHP.

I had some answers but I couldn't solve the problem :

[I can connect to an FTP server with PHP but can't ftp_nlist even with passive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467572/i-can-connect-to-an-ftp-server-with-php-but-cant-ftp-nlist-even-with-passive-mo)

[I can't work on a FTP server with PHP, the connection works, but I can't get files, or other things. It works with FileZilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151836/i-cant-work-on-a-ftp-server-with-php-the-connection-works-but-i-cant-get-fil)

Thank you

Comment: That's the same code as in your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50467572/850848 - Except that now you try an active mode. I'm aware that I have suggested that myself. But I also warned you that it's unlikely to help. As you didn't explain, why you try the active mode, you will naturally be getting suggestions to use a passive mode (What I would do too, had I haven't known the context).

Comment: Moreover your question title says "passive mode", what is not true with this code. - And it's actually your 3rd question about the same problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry for spaming with the same problem, but it's quite stressful,  the deadline is approaching and I'm still stuck on this problem

Comment: Do you know if the FTP server can forbid access to some commands ? In that case I won't be able to do anything with PHP and I will have to use WinSCP and automatize the data retrieval

Comment: You are abusing this site. Also, I've already guided you to obtain some useful information about your problem. And you didn't provide any of them in this post. Are you expecting poor folks here to waste their time asking you for the same information I did already?

Comment: I updated my post with the links of the 2 previous questions

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is used to turn on or off passive mode. Because you used false, passive mode is turned off. Change it to:

```
$pasvMode = ftp_pasv($ftpStream, true);
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I copy/pasted it stupidly, I was trying something but it didn't worked either